# Demographics and interests data not displaying in GA for React native app

Tags: google-analytics, react-native, react-native-ios

I have received each and every data under real time, audience except demographics and interest data in it, **no data** haven't display in this session, did anyone faced this issue in react native app using **react native google analytics bridge** plugin ?

Answer (score -1):

"react native google analytics bridge", This plugin is working fine, but we have to wait a few days after app deployment.

Then based on live data, google analytics will start analyzing the data then it will create the data relevantly under GA.